# Using pow(x,y) in large numbers

Tags: c++, math.h

I am inputting a number n where 1<=n<=10^5. I need a number of length n. So I use pow(10,n-1) but it doesnt work when n=100000. What is the error ?

EDIT: Its codeforces div2 round 152 problem B.

Chilly Willy wants to find the minimum number of length n, such that it is simultaneously divisible by all numbers Willy already knows (2, 3, 5 and 7). Help him with that.

A number's length is the number of digits in its decimal representation without leading zeros.

Input
A single input line contains a single integer n (1 ≤ n ≤ 10^5).

My code works upto n=19. It fails on pretest 9.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int f=0;
unsigned long long n;unsigned long long out;
cin>>n;
unsigned long long num=1;unsigned long long lim=10;
for(unsigned long long z=0;z<n;z++)
{num=num*10;lim=lim*10;}num=num/10;lim=lim/10;
for(;num<lim;num++)
{
if((num%2==0)&&(num%3==0)&&(num%5==0)&&(num%7==0)){f=1;out=num;break;}
}

if(f==1){cout<<out;}
else if(f==0){cout<<"-1";}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need a number with 100000 digits?

Comment: You tell us what's the error!

Comment: you should use arrays t store such numbers. what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with big numbers is not trivial; you cannot just use built-in types like `int`, `double`, `long`, etc for this. In order to calculate a number with 100000 digits, you need to have more than 300000 bits (a few kilobytes); this is in no way easy. Instead, you can print the answer without calculating it!

Saying that a number `num` is divisible by 2, 3, 5 and 7 is the same as `num % 210 == 0`. So the answer to your question looks like this:

```
100000000000... (really many zeros) ...00000xy0
```

All you need is to find two digits x and y, and print the above "number".

So you have to calculate `pow(10, 99999) % 210` without calculating `pow(10, 99999)`. To do it, start with `pow(10, 0) = 1` and multiply by 10 successively:

```
pow(10, 0) % 210 = 1
pow(10, 1) % 210 = (1   * 10) % 210 = 10
pow(10, 2) % 210 = (10  * 10) % 210 = 100
pow(10, 3) % 210 = (100 * 10) % 210 = (1000 % 210) = 160
pow(10, 4) % 210 = (160 * 10) % 210 = (1600 % 210) = 130
pow(10, 5) % 210 = (130 * 10) % 210 = (1300 % 210) = 40
...
```

After you calculate `pow(10, 99999) % 210` in this manner (suppose it's `xyz`), adding `210 - xyz` will make the number divisible by 210. So, to output the answer, print `1`, then print 99996 times `0`, then print `210 - xyz`.

Comment: Thanks that's just what I was looking for. Seems a stupid question now.

Answer (score 1):

For typical 32 and 64 bit floating point data types (`float` and `double`), they are constrained to the range:

```
float:  3.4E +/- 38  (that is, 3.4 * 10^(+/-38))  (with 7 digits of precision)
double: 1.7E +/- 308 (that is, 1.7 * 10^(+/-308)) (with 15 digits of precision)
```

A number with 100000 digits is waaaay outside the range of these datatypes. Hence, it fails (in some way), though you haven't told us how it fails.

Comment: I have updated my question with my code.